# Converting bytes to bits?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.6 and I need to convert an integer to a list of individual bits. For example, if I have:

```
def bitstring_to_bytes(s):
    return int(s, 8).to_bytes(8, byteorder='big')

command_binary = format(1, '08b')
bin_to_byte = bitstring_to_bytes(command_binary)
```

This currently outputs `b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01'`.

But I need to have in a list of integers (but in a hex type format) like so `[0x00, 0x00 ... 0x01]` in order to pass it to another function. I am stuck at this part.

Comment: `list(bin_to_byte)` would give you a list of integers, is that what you want? You won't see `[0x00, ...]` because that's not how integers are represented in output, although that's a valid literal form.

Comment: You can try `map(int, bin(str(num))[2:])`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it needs to be in that form since I am going to be sending data over an SPI connection

Comment: This appears to be close, sans formatting `list(map(hex, tuple(s)))` --> `['0x0', '0x0', ..., '0x1']`

Comment: @dbosk you need to *properly specify* what you want. As is, the example output you provided is *exactly equivalent* to the results of `list(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01')`. So if that *isn't* what you want, then you need to tell us exactly what that is.

Comment: list(map(hex, (bin_to_byte))) do not need tuple

Comment: @Mr_U4913 yes, but note both of these return *lists containing strings*, but the question, as written, is explicitly asking for a list of *ints*. Which again, then the answer is simply `list(bin_to_byte)`

Comment: @dbosk So, there is *absolutly no distinction* between a integers in hex or decimal format. The only difference is how they are being printed to screen, or how they are being interpreted as literals, but they are the exact same objects. What *exactly* do you need?

Comment: With the 0x prefix, Python can distinguish hex and decimal automatically.

Comment: yup I see what I misunderstood. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a simple list-comprehension with cast into `bytes`type?

```
bin_to_byte = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01'
list_of_bytes = [bytes([i]) for i in bin_to_byte]
print(list_of_bytes)
# [b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x00', b'\x01']
```

It does almost the same as `list(bin_to_byte)` expect it will forces to keep `bytes` rather than `int`. If you do need a list of `int`, then yes, `list(bin_to_byte)` is enough.

As you can see, each items of the list are not `int` nor `str` but `bytes`:

```
>>> isinstance(list_of_bytes[0], str)
False
>>> isinstance(list_of_bytes[0], int)
False
>>> isinstance(list_of_bytes[0], bytes)
True
```

Because the problem while using [`hex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex) is that it will transfrom your items to string even if they have the hexadecimal form e.g

```
bin_to_byte = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01'
list_of_hex = list(map(hex, (bin_to_byte)))
print(list_of_hex)
# ['0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x1']
print(isinstance(list_of_hex[0], str))
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
list(map(lambda b: bin(int(b)), list(str(bin( <your integer> ))[2:])))
```

OR

```
list(map(lambda b: hex(int(b)), list(str(bin( <your integer> ))[2:])))
```

It's ugly, but I'm pretty sure it does exactly what you need it to.

Comment: The OP has a list of `int`s as their desired output. These methods provide lists of `str`. I think the OP is vague about their requirements though.

Comment: it sorta works, it gives me a list of strings. Is there any way to make it maintain a hex format? I'll edit the question

Comment: Not sure, I'd have to really sit down and test stuff out. I know when you use hex or binary in python i.e. 0x1 or 0b1, it reads it as an int. But if you lose the hex formatting. 

so if you do [0x1, 0xff, 0x3], python takes it in as [1, 255, 3]